# Render error: "mongodb node module error is not found" -(depolyment error)

Tags: mongodb, deployment, render

In my package.json ,the mongodb module information is there and in local deployment successfully my application is running but when I deploy to render it is giving error "mongodb module not found" like this:-
[Render depolyment error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UlfE.png)

This is screenshot of package.json file:-
[package.json information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pt1u3.png)

I googled about my error and read documentation but I did not catch my error. Please help me to solve my problem.

Comment: It might sound stupid, but did you run `npm install` when you deploy? Without running `npm install` the modules simply do not get installed, so even if they are in the package.json, their code is not there.

Comment: Yaa..I did not build. Thank you SyncroIT for help.